# Unable to find a reference for some old code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am rebuilding an old project from a long time ago, which i did not create. I've searched around to no avail and cannot find what the reference for "DMB" shown below is. Has anyone come across this before? Or shall I rewrite it?

```
    protected void ErrorText(string error)
    {
        ErrorLabel.Text = error;
        if (playErrorSound && error.Length != 0)
        {
            DMB.Web.Sound sound = new DMB.Web.Sound();
            sound.SoundUrl = "ding2.wav";
            ErrorLabel.Parent.Controls.Add(sound);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What `using` do you have in your directives section?

Comment: Is there a missing reference under project references? Might give you an idea what it is

Comment: Nothing obvious on nuget unfortunately: https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=DMB

Comment: @MattEvans I also searched and all I got is Dave Mathews Band

Comment: @KobyDouek Nothing useful, just a few system references.

Comment: @MattEvans Unfortunately not. Agree all I have found is a band, probably not the DMB i want!

Comment: @OllieSharratt When you hover with the mouse over the `DMB` class in your IDE, what full path do you get ?

Comment: @KobyDouek No path unfortunately. However, I have now found the library file hidden inside my companys file server after a long while of looking! All seems to be functioning!

Answer (score 0):

Just create a UserControl called Sound with a  SoundUrl property. Once you can compile you can see what context it was used in.